# How to maintain session in Android Kotlin Webview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I have a Webview app in Android Kotlin in which user logs in and use the app. The problem is when user logs in and closes the app, next time when he opens the app, he goes to the login page, he should be logged in. I need to maintain session (or cookie) so he doesn't need to login again unless he logs himself out.

I have a running app in JAVA but that is so old, I cannot copy paste the code. I have gone through many answers but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this configuration for projects that requires WebView's.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private fun configureWebView(webView: WebView?) {
    webView?.settings?.userAgentString = getUserAgent()
    webView?.settings?.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
    webView?.settings?.databaseEnabled = true
    webView?.settings?.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView?.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView?.settings?.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
    webView?.settings?.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
    webView?.settings?.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
    webView?.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    webView?.scrollBarStyle = WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY
    webView?.isLongClickable = false
    webView?.setOnLongClickListener {
        true
    }
    webView?.settings?.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
}
```

The two main methods that you should check if they work for you are `databaseEnabled` and `domStorageEnabled` also if you use Javascript for that you should check `javaScriptEnabled` too.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @axierjhtjz I am using these settings:
`// Webview Settings
        webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webview.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webview.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webview.settings.allowContentAccess = true`

Comment: Try setting setDatabaseEnabled = true also.

Comment: I used your settings but no luck :( I think CookieManager should be used here but I don't know how to use it.